# LINQ: How to Sum over Grouping using method style linq?

Tags: linq, grouping, sum

In the code below I'd like to do a sum for OBFY and CFY separately within each grouping in deptGroup. Anyone have any ideas, I've tried a coupla things but can't get it. Thanks!!

```
  var deptGroup = prodCostsTotals.AsQueryable()
                                 .Select(r => dt.Rows.Add(new object[]
                                     {   
                                       Convert.ToInt32(r.Field<string>("Proc")),  
                                       r.Field<string>("UnitL"),
                                       r.Field<Decimal?>("OBFY"),
                                       r.Field<Decimal?>("CFY")
                                     })).GroupBy(g => g.Field<string>("Proc"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me you are overusing `DataRow`s. If you had your data in a nice class, you could write it like this:

```
data.GroupBy(x => x.Proc)
    .Select(g => new
                 {
                     Proc = g.Key,
                     OBFYSum = g.Sum(x => x.OBFY),
                     CFYSum = g.Sum(x => x.CFY)
                 })
```

But if you really want to start with a `DataTable` and add the intermediate result to another `DataTable`, you could do it like this:

```
prodCostsTotals.AsQueryable()
               .Select(r => dt.Rows.Add(new object[]
                   {   
                     Convert.ToInt32(r.Field<string>("Proc")),  
                     r.Field<string>("UnitL"),
                     r.Field<Decimal?>("OBFY"),
                     r.Field<Decimal?>("CFY")
                   }))
               .GroupBy(g => g.Field<string>("Proc"))
               .Select(g => new
                 {
                     Proc = g.Key,
                     OBFYSum = g.Sum(x => x.Field<Decimal?>("OBFY")),
                     CFYSum = g.Sum(x => x.Field<Decimal?>("CFY"))
                 })
```

Note that I have no idea whether your use of `AsQueryable()` will have any effect on the first part of this query, but it certainly won't have any effect on the grouping.